# Fetch dates from SQL Server vs PostgreSQL using VDF & MERTECH

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql

I'm currently using a command on PostgreSQL at the beginning of my program to use British date style:

```
SET DATESTYLE TO ISO, EURO
```

We are testing SQL Server and I cannot find ANY equivalent function.

```
dbcc useroptions set language 'British', dateformat dmy;
sp_configure 'default language', 23 reconfigure with override;
SET DATEFORMAT dmy;
```

These are some of the things I have tested without any luck. While I see the correct values when `dbcc useroptions` gets queried everything remains the same; `YYYYMMDD`.

Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Comment: http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=62891

Comment: What does "everything remains the same" mean? How exactly are you getting YYYYMMDD output? Can you show an example?

Comment: When you query a DateTime through SQL Server Management Studio, it will display as yyyy-mm-dd.  It's important to understand that this is how SSMS displays dates.  language and dateformats are used when interpreting dates.  Example:  1/2/2014  Is this Jan 2nd or Feb 1st?

Comment: My main language is VisualDataflex, I'm sending a query from there, "SELECT date_field from database.table" field type is date. This returns YYYY-MM-DD where I need to get DDMMYYYY.

Comment: You have a couple choices.  You can convert the date to a string in SQL Server, or you could format the date in VisualDataFlex.  I know nothing about VisualDataFlex, but I suspect there is a way to format the date the way you want it. From experience, I can tell you that converting the data to a string in SQL Server will be the wrong approach because you should do mundane things like formatting a date time on the client computer instead of the server.

Comment: While I agree @GMastros, we have everything working in PGSQL at this moment and saddly this is a huge program now. Rewriting all the query's is not an option anymore and formating the dates in every query either using VDF or SQL aint an option either. I'm just trying to mimic that "SET DATESTYLE TO ISO, EURO" behavior.

Comment: You should really fix the dates on the client side - for PostgreSQL too. If someone proposed the `DateStyle` parameter as a new feature now, they'd never get it accepted. It's only supported as a grandfathered compatibility option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is NOT @ database level. As everyone pointed out the database wont convert the output.
Using Postgres the configuration line is:

```
datestyle = 'iso, dmy'
```

This take's care of the issue.
In MSSQL we had to use something else at "driver level", the command is:

```
SQL_USE_DATAFLEX_FORMAT set to true
```

And this would take care of the issue. My original question was malformed as I never said what was the main programming language and I apologize for that.

Thanks a lot to everyone as all the answers were right.

Comment: So instead of having SQL Server transform dates into your preferred ambiguous format, you're going to have the driver transform every single value on the way through? Think about that for a moment - what do you think that will do to performance?

Comment: As I stated before, we reached a point of no return... I have no other choice but to "mimic" Postgres. VDF has no native suport for other databases but Mertech does this job for us. This results on a performance increase over the native VDF database anyway.

Answer (score 4):

If the data type is date then set dateformat etc. does not affect how SQL Server will output it *as a date* - it's a *date*, not a string. Notice these all output YYYY-MM-DD:

```
DECLARE @d DATE = GETDATE();
SET DATEFORMAT DMY;
SELECT @d;
SET DATEFORMAT MDY;
SELECT @d;
SET LANGUAGE BRITISH;
SELECT @d;
SET LANGUAGE US_ENGLISH;
SELECT @d;
```

These settings affect how *strings* are *interpreted*, not how *dates* are *displayed*.

**The answer** - preferred - is to apply such formatting at the client - surely VisualDataFlex has some string formatting functions equivalent to C#'s Format() or ToString() capabilities. But still you should be careful if you want to present users with local, regional formats like d/m/y - they are bound to be misinterpreted by someone. Is 5/7/2014 May 7 or July 5? Depends on the reader.

**The workaround** - much less desirable - is to muck up your queries with string formatting at the server.

```
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(10), col, 103) FROM dbo.tablename;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Aaron, but at this point our code is sooo big that replacing the query's is not an option.

Comment: @Solrac So you are looking for magic? Nothing is going to force SQL Server to output *dates* in DD/MM/YYYY format, sorry. This has to be done either by string conversion in the query or interpretation / conversion at the client.

Comment: I'm not; this is currently working with PGSQL, im looking for the same deal in MSSQL. But I think that my problem will be on how the "object" is beign returned now that you mention this.

Comment: Code that is "sooo big" should not be an excuse for doing things the wrong way.

Comment: I agree, im not the main developer though... I, have no other choice.